# Can currency in the Wizarding World be melted down?

Tags: harry-potter, money

In the Wizarding World, there are bronze Knuts, silver Sickles, and gold Galleons. Can these coins be melted down into precious metals (thus a Galleon is literally worth its weight in gold, or whatever it is made of)? Or is there some magic that prevents this?

Comment: Do we even know that Wizarding currency uses real gold?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Goblin coins probably can't be melted

We know that the coins are minted by goblins and that they can put protecting magic in metal items.

Hagrid mentioned indestructible goblin armors...

> "Oh yeah. Firs' we presented him with a nice battle helmet -goblin-made an' indestructible, yeh know - an' then we sat down an' we talked.'"
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix*

...and we know about the special properties of Goblin-wrought silver.

> “Oh yes. It is a copy—en excellent copy, it is true—but it was Wizard-made. The original was forged centuries ago by goblins and had certain properties only goblin-made armour possesses. Wherever the genuine sword of Gryffindor is, it is not in a vault at Gringotts bank.”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*
>
> “Muggle-born,” he said, “Goblin-made armour does not require cleaning, simple girl. Goblin’s silver repels mundane dirt, imbibing only that which strengthens it.”
>
> *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

Moreover, we know that the coins are cast under the responsibility of a single goblin, indicating a process that is at least a bit more artesanal than our own coins, with the supervision of a goblin. That points to some magic being actually involved in the making of wizarding currency.

> The coin gleamed fat and yellow in the light from the torches.
>   “On real Galleons ***that’s just a serial number referring to the goblin
>   who cast the coin***. On these fake coins, though, the numbers will
>   change to reflect the time and date of the next meeting.
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix.*

Additionally, goblins are probably aware of this potential problem since they trade muggle money for wizard coins and thus find a way of dealing with the muggle economy to get a profit out of that money.

> "Goblins manage to get muggle money back into circulation after muggles have changed it into wizard money at Gringotts. They are like 'Fences'"
>
> *JK Rowling - quote froom AOL chat 2000*

So while we don't know for sure it's not much of a leap to assume goblin gold comes with strong protection.

Comment: It is a good a answer, but i have an impression that goblin made armor,  weaponry etc. is custom- made with great care. Knuts, on the other hand seem mass-produced...

Comment: @D.O.B.Y2.0 actually I think I read somewhere that each coin has a mark telling the goblin that minted it, so maybe the process is somewhat more artesanal than our own coins.

Comment: nice. if you could find the source it would support your argument...

Comment: @D.O.B.Y2.0 there I found the quote

Comment: nice, pity i cant double UV for the research effort